# giving output bits of counter to logical gates in system generator

Tags: output, counter, xilinx-system-generator

I have a counter block in  **system generator** which has a 3 bit output. The block is shown below:

[image: Counter Block Symbol]

As is apparent from the figure, it's output is represented by a single line not three. I need to give its output bits to logical gates such as AND, OR, etc. but I do not know how to access the output bits (as I said; the output is represented by a single line). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a block called bitbasher. It's a block with which you can individually manipulate the bits on a line. If you open it you should be able to write some code. Just write something like: $$b = \{a[1]\}$$ $$c=\{a[2]\}$$ $$d=\{a[3]\}$$
It'll create 3 outputs (b,c and d) and 1 input (a). 
The number within the brackets mean the number of the bit of the line you want to use.

For further reading I suggest: http://www.xilinx.com/support/sw_manuals/sysgen_ref.pdf.

When I was learning how to use system generator, it helped a lot.

Comment: Dear Tom, I cannot make multiple output since in description part, it does not go to next line(I have tried several keys but non of them works). What should I do to write several expression?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, my studies are keeping me quite busy. In the block parameters (accessed by double clicking the block) it should have a space for the bitbasher expressions. It should be in the basic tab.

Comment: If I was able to use system generator I would post screenshots to make it more clear, but it's not installed on any of my personal computers, only on the computers on my campus.